# Ingress .yml file isn't being applied to GKE but works fine in minikube

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I've been using minikube and this yml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-cluster-ip
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: server-cluster-ip
                port:
                  number: 5000
```

I've installed helm on my GKE cluster and installed ingress-nginx via helm following their directions [here.](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#using-helm)

I kubectl apply my k8s and they all spin up besides the ingress-service from the file above.

Any help is much appreciated.

I've tried this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  namespace: my-ingress-nginx
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/*
            backend:
              serviceName: server-cluster-ip
              servicePort: 5000
```

I'm really stuck here. Not seeing ingress-service show up like I would in minikube and I have no idea why.

server-cluster-ip:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-cluster-ip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: server
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
```

client-cluster-ip:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-cluster-ip
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: web
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

The deployments and the clusterIp services above are being applied to the cluster but the ingress-service to direct traffic to them is not.

Services:

```
NAME                                    TYPE           
client-cluster-ip              ClusterIP      
kubernetes                              ClusterIP      
my-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   
my-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      
postgres-cluster-ip            ClusterIP      
redis-cluster-ip               ClusterIP      
server-cluster-ip              ClusterIP
```

the my-ingress-nginx-controller and my-ingress-nginx-controller-admission was created when I did `helm install my-ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx`

Why can't I create an ingress service?

Comment: What is the error you are receiving when applying it? Any guides you used when setting it up? Please check this link on [how to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized I needed to open port 8443 from the [documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#gce-gke).

So I went to the [firewall list](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list) in google cloud. Found the rules that had tcp:80,443 in the Protocols / ports. Clicked it, clicked edit and added 8443 to it.

I had an error after but this fixed it:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-resource
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip
              servicePort: 3000
          - path: /api/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: server-cluster-ip
              servicePort: 5000
```

Notice I changed * for ?(.*)